# iOS - filtering UITableView by UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, uitableview, filter, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a `UITableViewController` with a `Search Bar` (which is implemented in a `UINavigationController`).  I added a `UISegmentedControl` to the navigation bar so I can implement a filter on the table view. My table view shows an `NSArray` which contains a list of contact (which are custom `Contact` objects). I want to filter by one of the properties on the `Contact` (let's call it `property`). I already have 2 arrays to handle the search car filtering. To set the new filter by `property`, do I have to create a new array that contains only the `Contact`s that have the `property`? Or is there a smart way to filter it without creating another array?

The reason I want to avoid creating another array, is that I already have 2 arrays for the search filtering. And if I'll create another one for the `UISegmentedControl` filter, I think I'll have to create another 2 arrays - one for the `property` **without** the search filter, and another for the `property` **with** the search filter.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you're holding your data, but if you are using core data and a NSFetchedResultsController then something like the following works.  I present a couple of segmented Controller views that allow the user to filter on date range, supplier etc.  Then build a compound predicate and refresh the table data.

```
- (void)setupFetchedResultsController
{


// 1 - Set the Entity
NSString *entityName = @"Invoice";

// 2 - Request that Entity
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:entityName];

// 3 - Filter if needed
// Use a NSCompoundPredicate
// This is a complex predicate as user can choose :
// Payment Status
// Invoice Date range
// Supplier

// Constant - always filter by AP
NSPredicate *predicateAP;

predicateAP = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"accountingType = %@ ",@"AP"];

// Array of predicates
NSMutableArray *predicateMutArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:predicateAP, nil];


// Invoice payment Status
NSPredicate *predicatePaymentStatus;

if (self.filterSelectString){
    if ([self.filterSelectString isEqualToString:@"Paid"]){
        predicatePaymentStatus = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"paymentReference = %@ AND accountingType = %@ ",@"PAID",@"AP"];
    }
    if ([self.filterSelectString isEqualToString:@"Unpaid"]){
        predicatePaymentStatus = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"paymentReference != %@ AND accountingType = %@ ",@"PAID",@"AP"];
    }
}
if (predicatePaymentStatus){
    [predicateMutArray insertObject:predicatePaymentStatus atIndex:[predicateMutArray count]];
}

// Invoice Date Range
NSPredicate *predicateDateRange;
if ([self fromDate] && [self toDate]){


      predicateDateRange = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dateInvoiceIssued >= %@ AND dateInvoiceIssued <= %@",[self fromDate], [self toDate]];
}

if (predicateDateRange){
    [predicateMutArray insertObject:predicateDateRange atIndex:[predicateMutArray count]];
}


// Invoice Supplier
NSPredicate *predicateSupplierSelected;

if (self.selectedSupplier){
        predicateSupplierSelected = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"supplier.supplierName = %@ ",[self.selectedSupplier supplierName]];
}

if (predicateSupplierSelected){
    [predicateMutArray insertObject:predicateSupplierSelected atIndex:[predicateMutArray count]];
}


request.predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:predicateMutArray];

// 4 - Sort it
// Array of sortDescriptors
NSSortDescriptor *sortOnSupplier = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"supplier.supplierName"
                                                                 ascending:YES
                                                                  selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
NSSortDescriptor *sortOnDateIssued = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"dateInvoiceIssued"
                                                                 ascending:NO
                                                                  selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];

NSMutableArray *sortDescriptorArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:sortOnSupplier, nil];

[sortDescriptorArray insertObject:sortOnDateIssued atIndex:[sortDescriptorArray count]];


request.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptorArray;

// 5 - Fetch it
self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                    managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                                                      sectionNameKeyPath:@"supplierNameSectionTitle"
                                                                               cacheName:nil];
[self performFetch];
```

}